# Very simple upload form for wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a very simple plugin in my wordpress. Now i have a function and i use add_submenu_page to add that function to my main function (plugin).

I want to add a upload form to upload images in this submenu_page . Images should be uploaded to wp-content/uploads.

So is there any simple form to do this? I want to do it with main wp functions but i don't know how to do it.

Just needing a simple form to upload images in wp-content/uploads folder. How to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i did the following for a plugin i built. Dead simple!

Firsty you need to enqueue the wordpress media upload like so:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
function my_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_media();

}
```

You then need to give the the input button an id of `upload_image_button` here's an example:

```
<input id="upload_image_button" class="button" type="button" value="Select Logo" />
```

To display the file location in an input, use the following:

```
<input size="50" id="upload_image" type="text" name="ad_image" value="" />
```

I hope this helps!